# Passing form value from one form/page to another - Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Here is an explanation of my question.

**I have 2 forms:**
add & add1

**2 pages:**
add.php & add1.php

and **2 functions:**
function post_add & function post_add1
when the user has fill and submit the form add, function post_add automatically redirect to user to add1.

I want to pass value (after the user fill it and submit it) from form *add*

`"echo Form::text('name', Input::get('name'));"`

to form *add1*, because you need to type the same thing on next form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Posting some code would really help!  Thanks!

Comment: How are you "redirecting" the user from one form to the other?

Comment: This is a function for redirection: return Redirect::to_action('products@add1'); Just after successfully completed form, redirect to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Session::flash();

Like so...

```
 function post_add(){
 //blah blah your code.
 $passvalues = Input::all();
 Session::flash('values', $passvalues);     
 Redirect::to('/add1');

  }

  function post_add1(){
  //Now you have access to that input...

  $oldinput = Session::get('values');
  //do whatever you need to with the old/passed input
  }
```

Or you could just do a with()....

```
     function post_add(){
 //blah blah your code.
 $passvalues = Input::all();

 Redirect::to('/add1')->with('values', $passvalues);

  }
```